# sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Can I join a table with a Stored Procedure which returns a table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use INSERT.. EXEC to store the data from the SP into a table or table-variable.  Then you can join to that.

Say the SP returns a table (a int, b varchar(10), c datetime)

```
declare @temp table (a int, b varchar(10), c datetime)
;
insert @temp
exec myproc 1, 10, 'abcdef'
;
select *
from @temp t join othertable o on ... etc
```

Without creating a temp table, if you also exclude table-variable, then the only option - provided the SP -does not take any- parameters, is to use OPENQUERY to run the SP to return a table.  Pseudo:

```
select *
from OPENQUERY(local_server, 'spname_no_params') t
join othertable o on ... etc
```

Comment: Can I join without creating a temporary table ?

Comment: Create the User Defined function if you want to join the result

Answer (score 2):

You can't join directly onto a stored procedure. So you either need to use the approach per Richard's answer, or you could convert the sproc to a table valued function.

e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fxnExample(@Something INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
SELECT A, B
FROM MyTable
WHERE Something = @Something
)
```

which you then use/JOIN on in a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.Foo, f.A, f.B
FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN dbo.fxnExample(1) f ON t1.A = f.A
```

The thing to note is you can't do everything in a user defined function that you can in a sproc so depending on what your sproc does, this may not be possible. Also, for best performance you should make it an inline table valued function like my example above. The alternative is a multi-statement table valued function which could give you poor performance due to the way that the execution plan produced will be based on an assumption of a very low number of rows being returned by it (i.e. 1) - so if it returned a larger number of rows then performance could be poor.

Here's a good MSDN article on it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/10/28/query-performance-and-multi-statement-table-valued-functions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. What you can do is put the output of that SP into a temporary table and use it to your join statement.